# How to use jQuery to produce TinyURL

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tinyurl

I'm trying to build a jQuery function that will allow me to produce a TinyURL from some other link for micro blogging reasons (yes, twitter)...  I found this tutorial from James Padolsey, but am not getting a response back from the call.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/create-a-tinyurl-with-jsonp/

```
function requestShortURL(longURL, success) {
    var API = 'http://reque.st/create.api.php?json&url=',
        URL = API + encodeURIComponent(longURL) + '&callback=?';
    console.log('tweet apit url: ' + URL);
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
        success && success(data.url);
    });
}

requestShortURL('http://www.mycompany.com', function(shortened){
    alert('new url: ' + shortened);
});
```

Comment: Check your Javascript console (Tools > Error Console in Firefox), or use Firebug's console - it may give a useful error message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hm that seems to work fine for me:

```
function makeTinyUrl(url)
{
    $.getJSON('http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?url=' + url + '&callback=?', 
        function(data)
        { 
            alert(data.tinyurl); 
        }
    );
}

makeTinyUrl('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111171/how-to-use-jquery-to-produce-tinyurl');
```

Comment: Think a proxy could be killing this?  I've copied everything you have here, and don't get any alert...

Comment: Well what does it output if you directly call the URL ( http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111171/how-to-use-jquery-to-produce-tinyurl&callback=test123 ) in your browser? I just tried it and it alerted and the Browser returns this: test123({"tinyurl": "http:\/\/tinyurl.com\/m2befh", "ok": true})